# On google maps click jquery update the text fields with latitude / longitude values

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

As the title says on mouse click I want to add a marker to the click location, and then show the coordinates in the proper text field, everything is working great, only the JQuery isn't updating my text field.

```
<script>
var map;
var markersArray = [];
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 15,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: false,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
  }
};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps'),
  mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
    deleteOverlays();
    addMarker(event.latLng);
    updateTextFields(latitude, longitude);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
    showInfo(window);
  });

}

function updateTextFields(lati, longi) {
  $('#inputLatitude').change(function() {
    $('#inputLatitude').val(lati);
  });
  $('#inputLongitude').change(function() {
    $('#inputLongitude').val(longi);
  });
}


function addMarker(location) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  markersArray.push(marker);
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&' +
  'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).resize(function () {
    var h = $(window).height(),
        offsetTop = 190; // Calculate the top offset

    $('#gmaps').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
  }).resize();
});

window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery change is for detecting change value of the input.
Just revrite your function like this :

```
function updateTextFields(lati, longi) {
  $('#inputLatitude').val(lati);
  $('#inputLongitude').val(longi);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I originally had first, the actual fix was I was using name="inputLatitude" on my text fields for php and forgot to include the id="" thanks though!